# How to rehydrate state stored aggregates in Axon Framework

Tags: spring-boot, axon

I have state stored aggregates in a PostgreSQL database. I'm testing replay by deleting the state stored tables and the token_entry table and restarting the application. All events will be replayed and aggregates are restored in-memory. However, my state stored tables stay empty. I was thinking that they would also be restored?

I'm using SpringBoot and latest Axon. The code, at this moment, is as simple as it can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you're using Axon's [State-Stored Aggregates](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/axon-framework-commands/modeling/state-stored-aggregates), they'll only be stored **as-is**. Hence, throwing away the stored instances and starting the application will not trigger a replay.

When removing `TrackingTokens`, or [initiating a replay](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-processors/streaming#replaying-events) by invoking `StreamingEventProcessor#resetTokens` (this is the recommended approach, by the way), you're effectively telling the Event Processors of your application to start event streaming from scratch.

This part of Axon Framework supports the so-called Query Side of [CQRS](https://developer.axoniq.io/cqrs/overview). The Aggregate support in Axon Framework is specifically for the Command Side of an application.

Long story short, State-Stored Aggregates don't have replay support. If you want your Aggregates (Command Models) to be replayed, you will have to use [Event Sourcing Aggregates](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/axon-framework-commands/modeling/aggregate) instead.

I hope the above clarifies a little about the misconception between Token and Aggregates from your question. And by the way, if you feel Axon's Reference Guide should be adjusted to clarify your situation, you're always free to [file an issue](https://github.com/AxonIQ/reference-guide).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I might file an issue for the docs. I was trying to look into how to view the current state of my aggregates. I hoped the framework would have something "ready-to-use" without having to write my own custom code.

Comment: Of course, glad to help! Looking forward to the issue, Rafiek. :-)
And on the support you're looking for, you mean read the Aggregate State at a specific point in time, right?

Comment: If my assumption is correct, I'd dub that as a Query Side consideration, as you're looking to "see state/date." Hence, that's a specific type of Query Model you'd need to write, which uses Axon's Event Processor logic to build and recreate. From there, if you need that to be dispersed over time, choosing a time-series database would be your easiest approach.